# golang-migrate unknown driver postgresql using terminal command

Tags: postgresql, go, migration, golang-migrate

When I try to migrate down my base using terminal command (`migrate -path scripts -database "postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5439/basename?sslmode=disable" -verbose down`) I got an error: `error: database driver: unknown driver postgresql (forgotten import?)`. How to fix it?

Comment: It should be `postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost:5439/basename?sslmode=disable`, read the doc carefully.

Comment: @Зелёный these entries are equivalent (I checked it just in case: ```error: database driver: unknown driver postgres (forgotten import?)```)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to build with specific tag to add the specific driver.

See documentation
https://github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/tree/master/cmd/migrate#with-go-toolchain

```
$ go get -u -d github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/cmd/migrate
$ cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/cmd/migrate
$ git checkout $TAG  # e.g. v4.1.0
$ go build -tags 'postgres' -ldflags="-X main.Version=$(git describe --tags)" -o $GOPATH/bin/migrate $GOPATH/src/github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/cmd/migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

For new versions of **Golang(Go 1.16+)**

1. If you want to **installed Versioned** version e.g:

`$ go install -tags 'postgres' github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/v4/cmd/migrate@$TAG`

Where `TAG=v4.1.0` or `TAG=v4.1.x` etc

2. If you want to **installed Unversioned** version e.g:

`$ go install -tags 'postgres' github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/v4/cmd/migrate@latest`